# Pass to the limit under the sign of integral

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I need to show that this integral converges to its limit, showing this only for a subsequence is also good enough for  me.

Consider $w_k \rightarrow w $ in $L^2$, $u_k \rightarrow u $ weakly in $H^1_0$, strongly in $L^2$ (passing to a subsequence we can say it converges also almost everywhere), $\Omega$ a bounded and smooth domain in $\mathbb R^3$.
$a \in C^0 (\mathbb R) $ s.t. $0 < \lambda \leq a(s) \leq \Lambda  \ \forall s \in \mathbb R$

$$\int_\Omega a(w_k) \nabla u_k  \nabla v  \rightarrow \int_\Omega a(w) \nabla u  \nabla v  ?$$

I tried splitting it as:

$$\int_\Omega a(w_k) \nabla u_k  \nabla v = \int_\Omega a(w_k) (\nabla u_k - \nabla u) \nabla v \ + \ \int_\Omega a(w_k) \nabla u \nabla v $$

So my problem is:
$$\int_\Omega a(w_k) (\nabla u_k - \nabla u) \nabla v \rightarrow 0 ? $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_\Omega a(w_k) (\nabla u_k - \nabla u) \nabla v  \text{ d}x \to 0$$

since $\nabla u_k \to \nabla u$ weakly in $L^2(\Omega)$ and $a(w_k)\nabla v  \in L^2(\Omega)$. This can be seen from

$$\int_\Omega |a(w_k) \nabla v|^2 \text{ d}x \leq \Lambda^2 \|\nabla v\|_{L^2}^2.$$